# Avoid accessing private properties directly from the same class

Tags: java

This is a very simple example where accessing directly could be dangerous

```
class Something{

      public static final int MAX=123;

      private int prop;     

      final void riskyMethod()
      {
          this.prop=800; //this is wrong
      }    

      final void safeSetProp(int x)
      {
         if(x<MAX) 
         {
            prop=x;
         }
      }

}
```

I know it could be done encapsulating "prop" in another class, 
and defining it there as private, but that's a lot of useless code overhead!

Is there a way to force the use of methods to access same class properties?

a keyword? any trick?

I confess I have done things like this to avoid accidental access by the same class

```
private int IKWIDprop;          //IKWID = I Know What I am Doing
```

I am sure you could know a better approach =)

Regards!

Comment: How would you eventually change a field value if every method in the class is forced to access the field through another method?

Comment: Actually using (overridable) setters is more risky than accessing a private field. What if someone subclasses your class and redefines the setter?

Comment: @Adriaan Koster, final added thanks, the threat to avoid in this question is in the same class, like protecting it from.. myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is your class, come on! You always know what you are doing. If you don't, write tests. I understand you want to force the usage of getter instead of raw field in case at some point in the future the getter will be equipped with some extra logic. But because this is your class, you are fully responsible and capable of maintaining this code.

Bizzare Hungarian notation only clutters the code. Unit test your class to make sure nobody damages your work (including yourself). Nobody reads documentation and Javadocs, not to mention nobody will understand `TIASCWIAFDPUGIage` (*`thisIsASpecialCaseWhenIAccessFieldDirectlyPleaseUseGetterInstead_Age`*), including you after a while.

BTW if you force the usage of encapsulating getter inside your class, how does the getter itself access the field? So go back to earth and be reasonable. Having a strong suite of unit tests is much more helpful, reliable and provides better *documentation*.

**UPDATE**: Actually, there is a (*sort of*) clean way. You can use AspectJ, with few clever pointcuts, will catch raw private field access excluding some special cases. It can be executed at compile time to fail the build or at runtime. The pointcut would say something like: "*each private field access from a method that is not annotated with `@ThisIsASetter` should generate compile time error*. Maybe somebody more fluent with AspectJ can write this?

Comment: this should be taken into account in big command of developers. Noone knows what other will write

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz you are right, I was thinking in something as annotation "@ThisIsASetter" that grants you access to "super"private properties, but that's just to speculative imagination haha, I really put the question to confirm or not, if something like that did exist, thanks

Comment: *@Hernán Eche*: see my update. AspectJ seems to fill the gap you are looking for.

Comment: @Tomas Nurkiewicz ok, I will check it, I would prefer native Java, but well, perhaps in Java 8? who knows, thank you

Answer (score 2):

no, there is no such keyword. I advice you to write good documentaton, comments and to promis to beat those, who will use direct assigning of the value

Answer (score 1):

One "trick" that comes to mind is to put any fields like this into an abstract class which provides the necessary getter/setter methods. Then, derive your "real" class from the abstract class, and now any writing to those private fields need to be done via the "safe" setter methods.

Of course, this is a ton of extra overhead, and it still doesn't prevent you from writing incorrect values in the abstract parent class anyway.

The point of private is to ensure that internal class invariants aren't disturbed incorrectly by code that consumes the class. As you note, it does not prevent the class itself from messing with them, because presumably the class knows what it's doing! If you want to ensure that certain invariants are correct prior to relying on them, you can always use `assert` statements. If they fire, you can look through your code and see what you've done that's caused the problem.

In general, your best bet is to just be careful with your code, rather than trying any "tricks".